# How to get built-in controls under particular tabs in excel VSTO c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, ribbonx

I am working in excel VSTO add-in.

In excel, having built-in tabs, groups, and controls in the ribbon. I need to get the list of built-in controls under the View tab in c#. From that list, I need to set the value of visible/enable property for the controls.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't manage built-in controls on the ribbon. The best what you could do is to repurpose built-in controls or build the ribbon from scratch. Read more about repurposing built-in controls in the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

See [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) for ribbon controls IDs.